# IF Statement in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, countif

Trying to identify the syntax to do this in Excel 2010:

Look for the string "Potomac" in a range of rows.
Wherever "Potomac" is found, count the whole numbers in the B and C column of that row.
Search all rows in the same manner and sum the result.

I know that a long COUNTIF or COUNTIFS could do this but I have not been able to identify the syntax.

Comment: Is there anything in columns B and C that shouldn't be counted?

Comment: There are only numbers.  The only number that should be excluded is 0.

Comment: I don't think it would matter even if it tried to count 0 though.

Comment: Do you mean count the whole numbers or sum them? (If the latter then my answer is useless).

Comment: I may be confusing everyone.  I mean count the number in the cell (1,2,3,4,5) etc...

Comment: You mean **sum** the numbers?

Comment: Yes sum the numbers in the columns and move to the next row.

Comment: In which case my answer holds

Comment: Ok guys:

You have all helped me tremendously.  I have used bits and peices of all of your information to solve the problem.  Here are my formulas used:

=SUMIF(A100:A148, "*" & "Potomac" & "*",B100:B148 ) +SUMIF(A100:A148, "*" & "Potomac" & "*",C100:C148 )

=SUMIF(A101:A149, "*" & "Potomac" & "*",D100:D148 )

This looked for any instance of "Potomac" in a range of rows.  The first formula searched and summed the contents of the range of B with the range of C and output the result.  The second formula did the same for the D column which represented a different set of data.  Endless Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data extends to 5 rows from row 1, try this single-cell formula:

{=SUM(IF(A1:A5="Potomac", B1:B5 + C1:C5, 0))}

This is an array formula, meaning you don't actually type the braces, but use Ctrl + Shift + Return once you've done editing.

(I'm at home without Excel so am doing this from memory. If it doesn't work it means I've slipped the syntax. Do let me know.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, values in A1:A5

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5;"Potomac";B1:B5;"<>0")+COUNTIFS(A1:A5;"Potomac";C1:C5;"<>0")
```

Comment: This is pulling data BUT it is not counting the number IN the cell.  IE if B14 contains a "2" instead of a "1".

Comment: That means that you dont wont to count you want to sum

Comment: +1: not what the user wanted but satisfies one interpretation of a very ambiguous spec.

Comment: Again I'm sorry for confusing everyone.

Comment: but using the same logic now you can replace countifs by Sumifs or even sumif, to sum you dont need the "<>0" condition